# GRAILS respond with atomic json values

Tags: json, grails, grails3

I have actions that make sense to return an atomic value of json (user/hasPrivilege, etc) and would like my response to just contain "true" or "false", I'd also like to be able to send raw numbers and strings. I think these would count as valid json, but get the error:

```
Value out of sequence: expected mode to be OBJECT or ARRAY when writing 'false' but was INIT
```

Is it possible to instruct Grails to serialize these when the accept header is json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those values are valid json it seems that the Groovy JsonOutput does convert them to a Json string:

```
import groovy.json.*
JsonOutput.toJson(true)
>>> true
```

​

So wouldn't it be possible to convert with JsonOutput and respond with that instead of the Grails `as JSON`?

Comment: Using the JsonOutput seems to work, but I've got to use the "render" method rather than "respond"